# Laravel 4 - How to insert multiple models?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4

Im trying to insert multiple models into the database but with no luck...
I have a form (blade) looks like this:

```
@extends('layouts.properties')

@section('content')

{{ Form::open(['route' => 'properties.store', 'class' => 'uk-form', 'id' => 'properties-form']) }}

@for ($i = 0; $i < Auth::user()->properties_count; $i++)

<fieldset class="uk-margin-large-top property-field-{{ $i + 1 }}">

{{ Form::select('boro[]', ['Pick Borough', 'Manhattan', 'Bronx', 'Brooklyn', 'Queens', 'Staten Island']) }}

{{ Form::text('house_num[]', Input::old('house_num'), ['class' => 'uk-form-width-small', 'placeholder' => 'House Num']) }}

{{ Form::text('street[]', Input::old('street'), ['placeholder' => 'Street']) }}

</fieldset>

@endfor

{{ Form::submit('Save Properties', ['class' => 'uk-button uk-button-primary']) }}

{{ Form::close() }}

@stop
```

In the controller, I have: (used array_filter to clear the unset values if the user only filled in 2 properties)

```
$boro = array_filter(Input::get('boro'));
$house_num = array_filter(Input::get('house_num'));
$street = array_filter(Input::get('street'));
```

Now I'm stuck... can't figure it out how to loop thru 3 arrays and save it to multiple models (rows).

Note: In my User model I did set hasMany Properties relationship.

My Property model looks like:
id
user_id
boro
housenum
street

So if in the arrays i have 2 addresses, I need to rows.

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't really understand your problem. Can you specifiy what your model looks like and which data you want to insert?

Comment: I have edited the original post, hopefully it's clear now...

Comment: Please be MORE specific wiht your model, the saved values are some kind of relation? and no offense really but the code is a bit unreadable. So what exactly is the problem?

Comment: I dont know how more clear then this i can be...

Answer (score 0):

```
// Get your input values
$boros = Input::get('boro');
$numbers = Input::get('house_num');
$streets = Input::get('street');

// Iterate through the arrays
$models = array();
$total = count($boros);
for( $c=0; $c < $total; $c++ ) {
  $models[] = array('boro' => $boros[$c], 'numbers' => $numbers[$c], 'street' => $streets[$c]);
}

// Insert all the models
DB::table('whatever')->insert($models);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$boros = Input::get('boro');
$streets = Input::get('street');
$numbers = Input::get('house_num');

$properties = [];

foreach ($boros as $key => $boro)
{
   $properties[] = [
     'boro' => $boro, 
     'street' => $streets[$key], 
     'housenum' => $numbers[$key],
     'user_id' => $userId   // probably needed too
   ]
}

// cleaning (and validation maybe?)
$properties = array_map(function ($property) {
    return array_filter($property);
}, $properties);


DB::table('properties')->insert($properties);
```